# Multiple :before vertical dots under decimal in <ol> tag

Tags: html, css, html-lists

> I am trying to achive this, but I don't know how. My solution is
>   wrong, but I don't know any different solution. I need multiple
>   :before tag in my li tag, because dots and numbers are in the same
>   li:before and I can't change position of numbers. Can you help me,
>   please? My code is here:

```css
/* Experiences */
 ol.experiences li {
     padding-left: 33px;
     margin-bottom: 2.5em;
     list-style: none;
 }

 .where {font-weight: 700; }
 .description {margin-top: 0.5em;}
 ol.experiences li {
     position:relative; /* so that pseudoelements are positioned relatively to their "li"s*/
     /* use padding-bottom instead of margin-bottom.*/ 
     margin-bottom: 0; /* This overrides previously specified margin-bottom */
     padding-bottom: 2.5em;
     counter-increment: custom;
 }

 ol.experiences li:before {
     position: absolute;
     left: -11px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5d192 12%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
     background-position: left;
         background-size: 2px 16px;
     background-repeat: repeat-y;
     padding: 2px;
     height: 100%;
     width: 1px;
     z-index: -24;
     display: inline-block;
 }
 ol.experiences li:before {
  content: counter(custom) " "; 
     left: -61px;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 0 5px;
         font-size: 39px;
    color: #cba425;

 }
 ol.experiences li:first-child:before {
    /* first li's line */
    top: 6px; /* moves the line down so that it disappears under the bullet. Adjust manually */
 }

 ol.experiences li:last-child:before {
     /* last li's line */
    height: 6px; /* shorten the line so it goes only up to the bullet. Is equal to first-child:before's top */
 }
 ol.experiences li:first-child {
   counter-reset: custom;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
 <ol class="experiences">
  <!-- Experience -->
  <li>
    <div class="where">Self-Reflaction</div>
    <p class="description">Define a manager's strong points and their areas of development.</p>
   </li>
  <li>
    <div class="where">Purpose</div>
    <p class="description">Having identified your primary abilities and motivations, we'll use our tailored expertise to pinpoint the industries, teams and roles in which you!ll be able to unite the two.</p>
   </li>
  <li>
    <div class="where">Achievement</div>
    <p class="description">Action plan to get you towards the current market hiring trends.</p>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="where">Actualization</div>
    <p class="description">Art of getting what you want, negotiation and communication.</p>
   </li>
</ol>         
</div>
```

[This is, what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsBXl.jpg)

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. You can't have `ol.experiences li:before { left: -11px; }` and `ol.experiences li:before { left: -61px; }` at the same time; this is physically impossible. So you'll have to find another solution. By the way, what's with the vertical blue line in "what I want"? Also, the snippet in your question doesn't produce "what I see".

Comment: Blue line is guide in Photoshop.

Comment: Code in snippet is fixed, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `flex` to draw a container filling the entire height and draw the dots from there (or `display:table/table-cell`).

You could use also `<hx>` for titles instead div, and wrap both title/text into a div or else meaningfull tag ... usefull for the styling in that case).

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: oli;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0em;
}

li {
  counter-increment: oli;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li:before {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px lighhtgray;
  margin: 0;
  content: counter(oli);
  width: 2em;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin:0 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top, gold, gray, gold, transparent 4px, transparent 10px) 50% bottom repeat-y;
  background-size: 3px auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1.6em white
}

li:last-of-type:before {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ol class="experiences w100">
  <!-- Experience -->
  <li class="green d-flex flex-nowrap">
    <div>
      <h2 class="where">Self-Reflaction</h2>
    <p class="description">Define a manager's strong points and their areas of development.</p>
      </div>
   </li>
  <li class="green d-flex flex-nowrap">
    <div>
      <h2 class="where">Purpose</h2>
    <p class="description">Having identified your primary abilities and motivations, we'll use our tailored expertise to pinpoint the industries, teams and roles in which you!ll be able to unite the two.</p></div>
   </li>
  <li class="green d-flex flex-nowrap">
    <div>
      <h2 class="where">Achievement</h2>
    <p class="description">Action plan to get you towards the current market hiring trends.</p></div>
   </li>
  <li class="green d-flex flex-nowrap">
    <div>
      <h2 class="where">Actualization</h2>
    <p class="description">Art of getting what you want, negotiation and communication.</p></div>
   </li>
</ol>
```